# Linux xargs tricks to rename a file

Tags: shell, unix, command, xargs

I want to copy files to a archive directory by

- removing the gz extension
- appending a date to the filename and then
- appending the gz extension back

Here is my try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gz'|xargs  -I{} cp {} archive/{}.$(date '+%Y%m%d').gz
```

Suppose there is a file called test1.txt.gz

what this does is it gives me

```
test1.txt.gz.20181214.gz
```

What i want is

```
test1.txt.20181214.gz
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gz'| sed 's/\.gz$//' | xargs -I{} cp {}.gz archive/{}.$(date '+%Y%m%d').gz
```

where you add an intermediate processing via `sed` to remove the ending ".gz" extension.

You also need to adapt the `cp` command and append ".gz" to the files that will be copied to avoid files not found errors `: cannot access '...': No such file or directory` as the `xargs` command will not have the full filenames anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gz'| parallel cp {} archive/{.}.$(date '+%Y%m%d').gz
```